# Enable both network interfaces on an HP Prolian ML150G6 server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hp-proliant

Is there a way to activate this other network interface (circled in red) on the HP Prolian ML150G6 server?

[image of the rear of the server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyQVi.png)

Comment: That thing's ancient but I'm pretty sure the other NIC port is used exclusively by the iLO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael is correct. The [HP documentation](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c01710806) states under Interfaces):

- Network: RJ-45 (10/100/1000 bits/s Ethernet) (1)
- Remote Management: HP ProLiant Onboard Administrator (Powered by the HP Integrated Lights-Out 100i Baseboard Management Controller)

The server only has a single NIC.